# How to print/echo return records of getrelated('relation-name')?

Tags: yii

```
array(
          'header'=>assignment::model()->getAttributeLabel('group_id'),    //column header
          'value'=>'($data->getRelated(\'phoneNumberGroupAssignments\')=== null)?"No related assignment registry":$data->getRelated("phoneNumberGroupAssignments")->group_id', //column name, php expression
          'type'=>'raw',
          ),
```

How to print/echo return records of getrelated('relation-name')?
So that we can check whether it working or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
$data->phoneNumberGroupAssignments
```

or in general:

```
$data->relation-name
```

It is possible, because Yii `CActiveRecord` redefines magic getter method `__get()` ([link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#__get-detail))

---

**Update**

So you can write such code:

```
array(
    'header' => assignment::model()->getAttributeLabel('group_id'), //column header
    'value' => '($data->phoneNumberGroupAssignments === null) ? "No related assignment registry" : $data->phoneNumberGroupAssignments->group_id', //column name, php expression
    'type'=>'raw',
),
```

Comment: i want to display it in admin.php ..so where to write it?

Comment: actually i want to de-bug before activation of above array code...so just i want to echo getralted() values. i want to use it in 'value'='model-name=>getralted('relaion-name')->attribute(),